# sqlite table query - need help obtaining the correct results

Tags: sqlite

I am writing an application using **SQLITE**.

One of the tables is *users* which includes the **user_id** and other field as name, email, etc. Another table is *groups* with a field **group_id** and other fields as group name.

[users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzM81.png)

[groups table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3au0Q.png)

Then I created a table **users_groups**, specifying which users are part of which groups, in this table we have the **user_id** and the **group_id**.

[users-groups table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Npq.png)

I can easily make a SEARCH of the groups in which for example, user 4 is.

**SELECT * FROM users_groups WHERE user_id = 4**

The result would be **groups 1, 2 and 6**, which is correct.

What I haven't been able to do, is to make a query in which I get the groups in which a user is **NOT** part of. If I make the following query:

**SELECT * FROM users_groups WHERE user_id <> 4**

The results would be **groups 1 and 3**, which is not correct, since user 4 is actually part of group 1 as well.

I've been trying with JOIN, WHERE, HAVING, etc... without success!!

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user is not member of a group, that group ID might not show up in the `users_groups` table at all, so you cannot use a simple SELECT on this table alone.

This query returns the user's group IDs:

```
SELECT group_id
FROM users_groups
WHERE user_id = 4;
```

This query returns all other groups:

```
SELECT group_id
FROM groups
WHERE group_id NOT IN (SELECT group_id
                       FROM users_groups
                       WHERE user_id = 4);
```